# How to addClass active using on scroll but not using a href id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having this trouble making a on scroll without using the `<a href="#nameID">` because most of the tutorials needed an id just to identify which `a` link needs to be active. I am trying to avoid adding an `id` there so that the link will stay `mywebsite.com` and not `mywebsite.com/#nameId`. 
What I am trying to do is this

> **Home** Blog About Contact

If scrolled to `div #blog` then the nav would be

> Home **Blog** About Contact

This is the nav list

```
<nav id="menu-center">
    <ul class="click crsl">
        <li><a class="page1 dot active"></a></li>
        <li><a class="page2 dot"></a></li>
        <li><a class="page3 dot"></a></li>
        <li><a class="page4 dot"></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This is the js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".page1").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#home").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
    $(".page2").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#blog").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

    $(".page3").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#about").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });

    $(".page4").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#contact").offset().top
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
<!-- point active carousel -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('li a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes, using event.preventDefault()

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/25fd6nov/

```js
$('.click a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  var id = $(this).data('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu-center">
    <ul class="click crsl">
        <li class="active"><a class="page1 dot" data-href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="page2 dot" data-href="blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a class="page3 dot" data-href="about">About</a></li>
        <li><a class="page4 dot" data-href=contact>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Updated Solution** https://jsfiddle.net/25fd6nov/1/

```js
$('.click a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');
  var id = $(this).data('href');
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top
  }, 1000);
});

$('#main').scroll(function(){
    var element_height = 300;
    var offset = $('#scrollContainer').offset();
    var positive =  Math.abs(offset.top)
    var divided = positive / element_height;
    var round = Math.round(divided);

    var current_element = $('#scrollContainer').children().eq(round);
    var id = current_element.attr('id');

    $(`li[data-li=${id}]`).addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;   
  overflow: auto;
}
#home{
  height: 300px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
}

#about{
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

#blog{
  height: 300px;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
}

#contact{
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
  width: 100%;
}

#scrollContainer{
  positive: relative;
  height: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="menu-center">
    <ul class="click crsl">
        <li class="active" data-li="home"><a class="page1 dot" data-href="home">Home</a></li>
        <li data-li="blog"><a class="page2 dot" data-href="blog">Blog</a></li>
        <li data-li="about"><a class="page3 dot" data-href="about">About</a></li>
        <li data-li="contact"><a class="page4 dot" data-href=contact>Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="main">
  <div id="scrollContainer">
    <div id="home"></div>
    <div id="blog"></div>
    <div id="about"></div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm trying to find the on scroll that adds active class

Comment: Why negative? Please explain.

Comment: Your code is for me to click tab and will be viewed as activated. What I'm trying to do is just scrolling to the specific div and the tab will be active. Like a carousel on a slideshow

Comment: @JohnDoe Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/25fd6nov/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
$('.navbar>a').click(function(e){
  //preventing the default href
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass(active)
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(document).scrollTo(href);
})
```

Comment: I'm trying the on scroll that triggers active class not the on click

Comment: try ($document).on('scroll',function(){})